# How to link to different pages with the same data

Tags: php, .htaccess

I got a problem that I can't wrap my head around. I'm using a simple search script that returns data from two tables.

The data are pages, for example a program page or a contentpage or a news page. On their own summary pages they all have the correct url.

For example on newssummary.php all articles link to news/news-item1.html (rewritten using htaccess, the actual page would be newsview.php) And on programsummary.php all articles link to program/program-name.html (which is actually programview.php).

Now my question:

Using the following query I get all my data

```
$content = "(SELECT * FROM snm_content WHERE title LIKE '%" . $term . "%' OR introtext LIKE '%". $term ."%')";
$contentcon             = $conn->query($content);
$contentcr              = array();
while ($contentcr[]     = $contentcon->fetch_array());
```

And show it in a foreach loop. How can I make sure the correct url is added on every result? So if I search for 'something' and a newspage and programpage both contain 'something' they will both have an url like this:

```
<a href="program/'.$arrayvalue['alias'].'.html">'.$readmore.'</a>
```

But this is only correct for program, because when I click on the newspage, it will go to program/news-item.html instead of news/news-item.html

Does anyone know a way on how to tackle this?

Comment: Can't you assign a variable to the first part of the url ?

Comment: Yes, simply add the type of content to '$contentcr[]' and use that to generate the correct urls.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.